# Append elements after index position with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

How to append received elements after certain index, so first two elements do not get erased?

```
<div id ="wrapper">
    <div id="picker1"></div>
    <div id="picker2"></div>
    <div class="results"></div> // delete this and append result,
                                // which is let say 10 div's class result
</div>
```

this

```
$('#wrapper').html(result), or $('#wrapper').clear().append(result)
```

deletes first two elements also, is there a way to clear all elements with index > 1 and apend after index > 1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#wrapper')
.find('div.results')
.remove()
.end()
.append(result);
```

Alternatively you can simply use `replaceWith` jQuery method.

```
$('div.results').replaceWith(result);
```

If you want to remove all the child elements which are at index > 1 then use this.

```
$('#wrapper')
.children(':gt(1)')
.remove()
.end()
.append(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i understand your question.

You can remove the `divs with index > 1` using

```
$('#wrapper > div:gt(1)').remove();
```

After you can append using

```
$('#wrapper').append("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector) pseudo-selector:

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
wrapper.find("> :gt(1)").remove(); // Remove indexes 2 onward
wrapper.append(result);
```

...but in the case of the specific HTML you quoted, you could just remove the div with the class "results".

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
wrapper.children(".results").remove();
wrapper.append(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wrapper *:gt(1)').replaceWith('<div>foo</div>')
// select everything in wrapper with an index >= 2
// and replace it with <div>foo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$('#wrapper')
 .append(result)
 .find('div.results')
 .remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple: `$('.results').replaceWith(result);`
See http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$('#wrapper .results').after(result).remove();
```